# How use SOA with nHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, soa

First of all, I'll clarify some words: when I use the word "*user*" you have to understand "*application user*" and the "*patient*" is an "item" from the model layer.

Let's now explain the context:

- A client application has a button "*get patient*" and "*update*", a text box "*patient name*" and a grid to display the patient returned after the click on the "*Get patient*" button.
- At server side I've got a WCF method GetPatient(string name) that searches the reclaimed patient and does some business logic to a *PatientEntity* used with nHibernate. That method returns a *PatientDto* (a mapping from *PatientEntity*). And I've got an *Update(PatientDto patient)* method to update the modified patient.
- The user can modify the returned *PatientDto* and click on the "*Update*" button.

So far I have two ideas to manage a "*session*" through this senario:

- First idea: I expose an "*ID*" property in my *DTO* so when the user clicks on update,  I search, at server side, the "*patient*" with the specified ID using nHibernate's "*GetByID()*", I update the result with the data from *PatientDto* and call the nHibernate's "*Update()*" method.
- Second idea: I create manually at server side a *CustomSession* (I use this name for clarity) class that encapsulates an *ISession* and exposes a session's unique id that will travel between the client and the server. So, when the client sends to the server the PatientDto and the unique session id, I can get the *CutsomSession* and update the patient with the *Update()* methods of the *ISession*

I don't like these ideas. Because the first is a lot of overhead and it doesn't use the features of nHibernate. And the second idea demands to the developer to manage himself the id of the *CustomSession* between the calls: It is error prone.

Furthermore, I'm sure nHibernate provides such a mechanism although I googled and found nothing about this.

Then my questions are:

- What mechanism (pattern) should I use? Of course, the mechanism should support an entity's object graph and not a single entity!"
- Does nHibenrate provides such a mechanism?*

Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sumary of what has been said:

- A nHibernate session lasts the time of the service call. That's, the time of the call of "*GetPatient(string name)*" no more.
- The server works with entities and returns DTO's to the client.
- The client displays and update DTO's. And calls the service "*Update(PatientDto patient)*"
- When the client triggers the service "*Update(PatientDto patient)*", the mapper gets the patient entities thanks to the ID contained in the DTO with a "*GetById(int id)*" and updates the properties which has to be.
- And finally, the server calls the nHibernate's "*Update()*" to persists all the changes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a Hibernate issue and in my opinion is a common misunderstanding. Hibernate is a OR-Mapper and therefor handles your database objects and provides basic transactional support. Thats almost it.
The solution for Sessionmanagement in Client-Server environments is for example the use e.g. Spring.net which does provide solutions (Search for OpenSessionInView) for your problem and integrates quite well with NHibernate.
The stateless approach you mentioned offers many advantages compared to a session-based solution. For example think about concurrency. If your comitt is stateless you can simply react on a failed Save() operation on the client side for example by reloading the view.
Besides your 2 good arguments for the use of Hibernae is, if done right, security aggainst SQL-Injection.

Answer (score 0):

One reason that I usually don't bother with ORM tools/frameworks in client-server programming is that you land at, usually, your first solution with them. It helps in making the server side more stateless (and thus more scalable) at the expense of some reasonably cheap database calls (a fetch-by-PK is usually very cheap, and if you immediate write it anyway, guess what the database is likely to do first on a write? Grab the old record - so SELECT/UPDATE may be only marginally slower than just UPDATE because it seeds the cache).

Yes, you're doing stuff manually that you want to push out to the ORM - such is life. And don't fret over performance until you've measured it - for this particular case, I wonder if you really can measure it.

Comment: I see at least 2 reasons to still use ORM even if I'm using your solution:
 * ORM is DB agnostic so I can change it just by modifying config file
 * I don't bother writing SQL (It's a relevant remark since I'm C# lad and LINQ is, at least to my project, better than SQL;))